# jQuery Animate through specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Is it possible to make an object animate from one position to another using a specific path? 
For example, while animating from pos1 to pos2, if there is a div with class "no-ok" in the way, it should not go there instead find the nearest div called OK on its left, right, up or down. If there is no div called ok, it should stop. 
The following image explains:

[image]

So far, I can only animate from pos1 to pos2, but I don't know how to check if there's div no-ok in the way, and how to find the nearest div with class ok.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="container">
        <div id="pos1"></div>
        <div class="ok"></div>
        <div class="no-ok"></div>
        <div class="ok"></div>
        <div class="pos2"></div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.container').click(function(){
    var pos1 = $('#pos1').position();
    $(this).animate({ 'top': pos1.top + 'px', 'left': pos1.left + 'px'}, 200, function(){
        //end
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation sturcture needs to be like this:

**[Here is jsFiddle to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/jW4eH/27/)**

```
var pTop = parseInt($('.container').css('top'));
var pLeft = parseInt($('.container').css('left'));

$('.container').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({'left': (pLeft * 2) + 'px'},1000,function(){
    //firt step = go 2x right
        $this.stop().animate({'top':  (pTop*3)  + 'px'},2000,function() {
        //second step = go 2x bottom
            $('.container').animate({"left": "-=100px"},1000);
            //third step = go begining left position
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant there can be any random div classes, so it should look if it is possible for it to move (eg. move to only div with class 'ok')

Comment: i couldn't understand your comment's question, i just did what i saw on your quetion picture. explain more spesific or select accpet answer if it worked mate.